# How to inject User to symfony controller

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I define AuthController as service and want test it. I add setUser method and want that DI inject it's using security context.

Something like that, but right:

```
$authController = $container->getDefinition('bundle_api.controller.auth');
$authController->addMethodCall('setUser', [function () use ($container) {
    return $container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
}]);
```

Comment: why don't u inject the 'security.context' service and in your setUser method use `$this->user = $security_context_definition->getToken()->getUser();`?

Answer (score 0):

If I would be confronted with your issue i would do one of next two things:

1 - Inject the 'security.context' and go from there

or

2 - try the di factories described in detail in the [Symfony2 docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html)